# How to add multiple checkbox into an itext table cell

Tags: java, checkbox, itext

I have a maintainable called data. I want to add checkbox's in my cell of marital status.

I have tried looking around all blogs but I can not get the right approach. I am new to itext java pdf but really need help.

Below is some code I have so far. I would like each cell element to appear with a checkbox beside it.

```
  PdfPCell c9;
     PdfPTable checboxtable = new PdfPTable(2);
      PdfPCell c27 = new PdfPCell();
      c27.addElement(new Phrase("8.Sex"));
       c27.addElement(new Phrase("male"));
        c27.addElement(new Phrase("female"));
        checboxtable.addCell(c27);
         PdfPCell c28 = new PdfPCell();
          c28.addElement(new Phrase("9.Marital Status"));

       c28.addElement(new Phrase("Married"));
        c28.addElement(new Phrase("Single"));
          c28.addElement(new Phrase("Sperated"));
        c28.addElement(new Phrase("Divorsed"));
          c28.addElement(new Phrase("widow(er)"));
           c28.addElement(new Phrase("others"));
        checboxtable.addCell(c28);
        c9 = new PdfPCell (checboxtable);
          c9.setPadding(0);
         data.addCell(c9);
```

Comment: Did you check the answer to this question: [How to create radio buttons inside a table?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-radio-buttons-inside-table) Also, using a generic tag for a `Chunk` could also help.

Comment: spelling and rewording

Comment: i saw it but couldnt figure it out. can u help please. an new to itext